# Which User Agent should i use in My Django App Deployed on Heroku which is requesting another link

Tags: django, heroku, http-headers, httprequest, user-agent

I have deployed a python django web app on Heroku. In that app there is a internal function requesting another url and the response 403 is coming in return.

The code that i used is

```
        url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=BANKNIFTY'
        headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'} 
        page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        print(page)
```

This Code is working fine in my local terminal as well as on browser and showing result. But in Heroku response **<Response [403]>** This is recieved.

Comment: Hey bro! Were you able to solve this? Please help

Comment: Hey there. Actually the problem was not with header or user-agent. The problem is of heroku and the link i am using of NSE. Heroku has two servers in US and UK and in both the places NSE link is not accessible and along with it. NSE has used a detector to check if someone is accessing this link from server, then it blocks it, so to avoid web scrapping. I implemented something else in this case.